# SwiftUI: NavigationSplitView title bar issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationsplitview

I’ve filed this as a bug with Apple (FB12119822) since I’m fairly certain there’s nothing wrong with my code, but posting here for posterity and in case other folks have found a workaround.

When navigating between list and detail sections in a NavigationSplitView, the title bar unexpectedly jumps between inline and large display modes. In some instances, the title appears to be empty until the navigation segue is complete, after which it suddenly renders in a large display mode, pushing view content down.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a NavigationSplitView with a sidebar of navigable List items and a detail view corresponding to the selected item with a navigation bar title
2. Navigate into the detail view

### Expected result

The navigation segue animates the origin title into the “Back” button of the navigation bar, and simultaneously animates the destination’s navigation bar title into a default (large) display mode

### Actual result

The navigation segue animates the origin title into the “Back” button of the navigation bar, but no destination title is displayed. When the segue completes, the ”Back” button text is replaced with the default text (“Back”) and the destination title suddenly appears. ([Screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz9wmzcr8kr7rop/Simulator%20Screen%20Recording%20-%20iPhone%2014%20Pro%20Max%20-%202023-04-14%20at%2018.35.45.mp4?dl=0))

### Additional observations

The above behaviour is exhibited when the NavigationSplitView’s List has a `selection` argument. When instead the `navigationDestination` modifier is applied, the title bar of **both** the origin list and destination detail view is impacted. ([Screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nqudiym2sg2btr/Simulator%20Screen%20Recording%20-%20iPhone%2014%20Pro%20Max%20-%202023-04-14%20at%2018.38.58.mp4?dl=0))

### Code samples

#### `List(selection:)`

```swift
import SwiftUI

fileprivate struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
}

fileprivate let items = (0...10).map { _ in Item() }

struct ListWithSelectionTitleBarJumpExample: View {
    @State var selectedItem: UUID?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedItem) {
                Section {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item.id.uuidString)
                            .tag(item.id)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Navigable rows")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Title Jump")
        } detail: {
            if let selectedItem,
                 let item = items.first(where: { $0.id == selectedItem }) {
                Text(item.id.uuidString)
                    .navigationTitle("Detail View")
            } else {
                Text("No selection")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListWithSelectionTitleBarJumpExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListWithSelectionTitleBarJumpExample()
    }
}
```

#### `List.navigationDestination`

```swift
import SwiftUI

fileprivate struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
}

fileprivate let items = (0...10).map { _ in Item() }

struct ListWithNavigationDestinationTitleBarJumpExample: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(value: item) {
                            Text(item.id.uuidString)
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Navigable rows")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Title Jump")
            .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { value in
                Text(value.id.uuidString)
                    .navigationTitle("Detail View")
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("No selection")
        }
    }
}

struct ListWithNavigationDestinationTitleBarJumpExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListWithNavigationDestinationTitleBarJumpExample()
    }
}
```

Comment: Still seeing this on iOS 17 beta as well. Have not been able to find a work around except for trying to manually switch to a navigation stack when things are collapsed by checking the horizontal size class but this creates a big headache with managing the hierarchy

Comment: Reported FB13348252.

Comment: I have other issues for the `NavigationSplitView`'s title for RTL languages, I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77689906/swiftui-macos-14-navigationsplitview-isnt-displayed-well-for-right-to-left-lan

Answer (score 5):

I believe `NavigationSplitView` gets confused when a detail view has a `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` that is different from the one in the `no selection` view.

For example, a large title vs no title, an inline title vs a large title, a title with an editor via Binding vs plain text title.

At least your `ListWithSelectionTitleBarJumpExample` could be "fixed" by adding a placeholder `.navigationTitle` to the "no selection" view:

```
// ...
} else {
    Text("No selection")
        // The workaround: 
        .navigationTitle(" ")
}
```

This is, obviously, still a bug, `NavigationStack` has no problem switching between title modes.

Comment: Thanks @zrslv, this seems to fix the issue for the title. But when I set ToolbarItems in the detailView, the button does not fade, and seems to appear after the detail view loaded. Do you have any idea/workaround for that?

Comment: @alpennec difficult to tell without seeing the code. I have some toolbar items in the detail view of my app and they seem to work alright. My advice would be to create a new SO question and provide some code. If you do, please post the link here.